# Swift OSX NSOpenPanel not changing selection

Tags: swift, macos, nsopenpanel

I am calling a `NSOpenPanel` so the user can select a file, but after the first selection is done the panel doesn't allow me to change the file when I click with the mouse on another file. It changes when I use the keyboard arrows but it doesn't when I click with the mouse.

```
@IBAction func selecionarImagemButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {

    let panel = NSOpenPanel()
    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    panel.canChooseDirectories = false
    panel.canChooseFiles = true
    panel.canCreateDirectories = false
    //panel.allowedFileTypes = ["jpg","png","pct","bmp", "tiff"]
    panel.allowedFileTypes = NSImage.imageTypes()

    panel.beginSheetModal(for: view.window!) { (result) in

        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
            self.logoFornecedorImageView.image = NSImage(byReferencing: panel.url!)

            self.logoFornecedorSelecionada = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008262/detailed-instruction-on-use-of-nsopenpanel/28015428#28015428

Comment: Why are you using the modal sheet?  Have you read other topics on NSOpenPanel?

Comment: By "after the first selection is done", do you mean click and click again or choose a file and run the panel again? Does clicking on buttons work? I tried your code and can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have read the other topics of NSOpenPanel including `Detailed instruction on use of NSOpenPanel` as suggested by Leo Dabus.

Comment: Willeke, I mean click on a file and after that try to click on another file without closing the Panel.