# How to display NSSavePanel in MacOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, io, swift4

I'm trying to show NSSavePanel (or any "Save File Dialog") on Mac OSX. I'm building COCOA application in XCode Version 9.3 (9E145) in Swift 4 (or 4.2? I'm not sure exactly).

I've tried everything...

Like this?

```
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    savePanel.begin { (result) in
        if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {


        }
    }
```

this?

```
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    savePanel.showsTagField = false
    savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "result.csv"
    savePanel.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue: Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.modalPanelWindow)))
    savePanel.begin { (result) in
        if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {


        }
    }
```

many many other ways...

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `savePanel.level = .modalPanel`and
 `savePanel.begin {
    if $0 == .OK {
        print("success")
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks!

Comment: this might help. It is NSOpenPanel but you can easily adapt for saving. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008262/detailed-instruction-on-use-of-nsopenpanel/28015428#28015428

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is your application sandboxed? (Project > Capabilities > App Sandbox)

If so, ensure that you change "File Access" for "User Selected File" to Read/Write.

When I do that, your first snippet works fine for me.

[image]